# Device orientation with UINavigationController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiinterfaceorientation

I am updating an App who need only 2 Views with the function shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation  portrait to landscape view.
The project is using UINavigationController so if I want the rotation working to portrait to landscape I had to implement all classes (16 in total) with this code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

So now the rotation is working but for all views only !! If I put this code only on classes where i need is not working at all.

How I can have the rotation working only for two views ?

Comment: xcode has no device orientation — it is just an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it for every controller, it is better to have those two view controllers observe [`UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW38) generated by the `UIDevice` object. Based on the notifications you can deal with rotating and laying out the subviews.

Comment: I'm a bit uncertain how to do what you suggested. Can you give some kind of example?

Comment: @Ben, I know its been sometime but I will reply anyways. The idea is to manually listen to the changes in orientation as we can't use the view controller provided functionality. Make both the controllers observe the notification. Once you are notified of the orientation, manually alter the layout yourself. Do the rotations, define new frames for the subviews.